# How to efficiently assign attributes from one pointcloud to another?

Tags: python, performance, point-clouds

I have two point clouds which are basically the same (X,Y,Z,Intensity) but one of them is gridded (and thus fewer points) and has an additional attribute 'classification'. My goal is to extrapolate the classification based on the position.

Assume pointcloud A (`pc_dst` in code snippet) has 6.000.000 points with X,Y,Z,Intensity. Pointcloud B (`pc_src` in code snippet) has 50.000 points with X,Y,Z,Intensity,Classification.

My idea is to take each point of A, look for all points with maximal distance in B, take their classification (the most frequent value) and assign this classification to the point of A.

I already have a function like this:

```
def getclass(p_dst, pc_src, rad = 0.2):
    '''
    pc_src = coarse pointcloud with classification
    p_dst = point from dense pointcloud with no classification
    '''
    return np.bincount(list(pc_src[pow(pc_src[:,0]-p_dst[0],2) + pow(pc_src[:,1]-p_dst[1],2) + pow(pc_src[:,2]-p_dst[2],2) < pow(rad,2),4])).argmax()
```

After that, I tried looping with:

```
for i in tqdm.tqdm(inputs):
    pc_dst[i,4] = getclass(pc_dst[i,:],pc_src)
```

But this is horribly slow.
Can someone help me find a solution with reasonable performance?

---> Edit: Some sample data (if necessary, I can share more)

Pointcloud A:

```
//X Y Z Intensity
5427.71386719 -6327.11523438 506.64389038 203.000000
5427.84130859 -6326.99609375 506.62570190 225.000000
5427.84863281 -6326.98876953 506.61660767 235.000000
5427.85058594 -6326.98681641 506.60430908 242.000000
5427.86572266 -6326.97265625 506.59909058 236.000000
5427.88574219 -6326.95410156 506.59271240 233.000000
5428.60937500 -6326.26416016 506.04458618 246.000000
5428.61132813 -6326.26171875 506.03640747 239.000000
5428.60791016 -6326.26464844 506.02410889 216.000000
5428.63134766 -6326.24218750 506.00170898 202.000000
5428.66015625 -6326.21582031 506.00579834 212.000000
5428.67675781 -6326.20019531 506.00299072 134.000000
5427.76416016 -6327.14990234 506.66101074 196.000000
5427.78662109 -6327.12890625 506.65771484 202.000000
5427.80712891 -6327.10937500 506.65109253 207.000000
5427.82177734 -6327.09570313 506.64410400 214.000000
5427.83398438 -6327.08398438 506.63629150 224.000000
5427.84277344 -6327.07568359 506.62750244 227.000000
5427.84570313 -6327.07226563 506.61849976 229.000000
5427.85449219 -6327.06396484 506.60830688 233.000000
5427.86669922 -6327.05224609 506.60079956 232.000000
5427.87939453 -6327.04052734 506.59341431 237.000000
5427.89160156 -6327.02880859 506.58441162 237.000000
5427.90332031 -6327.01757813 506.57958984 236.000000
5427.92138672 -6327.00097656 506.57260132 221.000000
5427.94970703 -6326.97460938 506.57049561 191.000000
5427.97656250 -6326.94970703 506.56799316 198.000000
5427.99218750 -6326.93457031 506.56039429 223.000000
5427.99462891 -6326.93212891 506.55139160 233.000000
```

Pointcloud B:

```
//X Y Z Intensity Classification
5427.70019531 -6327.10009766 506.60000610 238.000000 2.000000
5427.70019531 -6327.00000000 506.60000610 229.000000 2.000000
5427.70019531 -6326.79980469 506.50000000 245.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.39990234 506.50000000 249.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.39990234 506.60000610 214.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.29980469 506.60000610 226.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.20019531 506.50000000 231.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.20019531 506.60000610 229.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.10009766 506.50000000 237.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.10009766 506.60000610 231.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.00000000 506.50000000 236.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6327.00000000 506.60000610 228.000000 2.000000
5427.79980469 -6326.89990234 506.50000000 246.000000 2.000000
5427.89990234 -6327.60009766 506.60000610 218.000000 2.000000
```

More detailed:

- Pointcloud A: https://justpaste.it/4fpli
- Pointcloud B: https://justpaste.it/9nmo0
- Expected Result: https://justpaste.it/3a4ic

Comment: Please post some sample data (like 20-length `p_dst`  and 5-length `pc_src`) with expected output. Just to make the testing easier and make the tester more confident and willing to provide the answer

Comment: @JanStránský I added some examples.

Comment: Some spatial sorting of the data like quadtrees could help. Have a look at [scipy KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree) and its [query_ball_point method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point). For further help, please provide some toy (really a few entries) input with expected output. Efficiency correctness can be e.g. checked by copying the arrays by themselves

Comment: Thanks for your input. The samples that I provided are too big? Concerning the KDTree, I think this is to speed up the neighbor search, but I think this is already in an acceptable speed. What I think of is to somehow vectorize the function (or something similar) instead of using a for loop.

Comment: I could not make work the code `return np.bincount(...)`. Can you explain a bit what it (should) does? I expected it to test each point from `src` with each point with `dst`, is that right or not?

Comment: Pretty much yes. It tests one point `p_dst` from `pc_dst` with each point of `pc_src` if it's in the radius `rad`. `bincount` and `argmax` determine the most frequent classification value. In order to test each point of `pc_dst`, I use the for loop (which I want to avoid).

Comment: Ok, in that case you do 6.000.000 x 50.000 tests. The point of the spatial tree is to do 6.000.000 x (much less then 50.000) tests, which should improve the performance..